# How can I solve for $a$ in $\frac {k-\frac 32}a+\frac 1{2a^2}+\digamma(a)-\digamma(a+n)=0$, where $\digamma$ is the digamma function?

Tags: digamma-function

How can I solve for $a$ for this following equation?

> $$\frac {k-\frac 32}a+\frac 1{2a^2}+\digamma(a)-\digamma(a+n)=0,$$

where $\digamma$ represents the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), i.e. it is defined as the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function.

Comment: That's not an equation...

Comment: forget to include a  =0

Comment: What is $k$? A constant?

Comment: yes. k and n are just a constant

Comment: You could first try using the recurrence relation of the digamma function which will give you: $F(a+n)-F(a)=\frac{1}{a}+\dots + \frac{1}{a+n-1}$.

Comment: yeap. already tried that. And i'm stuck at the part on how to simplify or change 1a+⋯+1/a+n−1 to a closed form.